# styling checkbox with angular directive

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to style an input type='checkbox' with an angular directive and my HTML layout looks like this

```
<div class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" ng-model="checked1" /></div>
<div class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" ng-model="checked2" /></div>
<div class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" ng-model="checked3" /></div>
```

My directive so far looks like this:

```
myApp.directive('checkbox', function($parse) {
    return {
        restrict: "C",
        compile: function(elem, attr) {
            var model = $parse(attr.ngModel);

            return function(scope, elem, attr) {
                var toggleValue = function() {
                    scope.$apply(function(scope) {
                        model.assign(scope, !model(scope));
                    });
                };

                var updateComponent = function(value) {
                    if(value == true)
                        elem.addClass('checkbox-active');
                    else
                        elem.removeClass('checkbox-active');
                };

                elem.bind('click', toggleValue);

                scope.$watch(model, updateComponent);
            };
        }
    }
});
```

The problem with this directive is that it searched the ng-model from the  not from the input inside the div so it would work if I had the layout like this

```
<div class="checkbox" ng-model="checked1"><input type="checkbox" /></div>
```

Can I change something into the compile of the directive so I make it read the ng-model from the input rather than from the div ?

Answer (score 3):

You do not need to read the ng-model attribute directly like that, ngModel exposes an api via ngModelCtrl. Your directive can do this

```
require: "ngModel",
```

and then in the link function, the ngModelController will be available

```
link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
```

In the link function you could check the state of the model and add/remove classes accordingly. You might also be able to just use ngClass and not even use a custom directive.

The docs for ngModelController are here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController

As for why it is being applied to the div and not the checkbox? You have class="checkbox" on the div. That is what is activating your directive. Move the class="checkbox" to the input.